# interaction between codes in old (prototype) and new (class) styles

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a library in **old style** like this

```
function A() { }
A.prototype.hello = function (s) {
    console.log(s);
}
module.exports = A;
```

Some application is using it like this

```
const {inherits} = require('util');
const A = require('./lib.js')
function B() {
    A.call(this);
}
inherits(B,A);
const b = new B();
b.hello('test');
```

I want to use a **new style** in library without any changes in application

```
class A {
    hello(s) {
        console.log(s);
    }
}
module.exports = A.constructor // ???????
```

**Question: What do I need to add in the last line for correct work?**

Comment: You've already asked this question before, the answer is still the same: it's not possible to use `A.call(this)` when `A` is a `class`, so don't use classes if you cannot change the subclassing code.

Comment: If you insist, your best bet would be `function A() { const instance = Reflect.construct(RealA, arguments, this.constructor); Object.assign(this, instance); Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(instance)); } A.prototype = RealA.prototype` where `RealA` is your `class` and the `A` function acts as a weird intermediate that copies the properties of the real instance to the object created by `new B`.